# C++ object creation without constructor call

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

In c++, creating an object without calling a constructor like this. Does this count as defined behavior? (Disregard the unfreed heap memory)

```
class Foo {
public:
    int *ptr;
    int a, b;

    Foo() { ptr = new int{}; }
    ~Foo() { delete ptr; }
    void set(int a_, int b_) {a = a_; b = b_;}
    void print() { std::cout << *ptr << a << b; }
};

int main() {
    char *array[sizeof(Foo)]; // note the pointer
    *((int**)array) = new int{3};
    ((Foo*)array)->set(1, 2);
    ((Foo*)array)->print(); // 312
}
```

Comment: No, this is completely and totally undefined behavior, for too many different reasons to list.

Comment: You are not creating an object, you are just casting an existing memory location to the object.

Comment: what's wrong with standard c++ syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a memory block that can hold the data for the object, but that is not an object.

An object consist of potentially a lot more than that slice of memory, and what exactly more is up to the compiler. It *could* be nothing more, but it could be a lot of other things.

Comment: As an addendum: If you're going to do this, you'll want to find your compiler's option for displaying class layouts, and your code will very likely be platform-dependent.  MSVC uses `/d1reportSingleClassLayoutX`, where `X` is the class' name (or part of its name).  Clang uses `-Xclang -fdump-record-layouts`, and to my knowledge you have to instantiate the class at least once before it'll generate (or maybe just output) the layout.